# Are allocators required to be interconvertible?

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion, allocator

I wondered for a long time how it is possible to assign an allocator of type A to an object expecting an allocator of type B. Check the following code:

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIAJykrgAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxBIAbKQADqgKhE4MHt6%2BASlpGQKh4VEssfFcSXaYDplCBEzEBNk%2BfoHVtQL1jQTFkTFxibYNTS257SO9Yf1lg5UAlLaoXsTI7BzmAMxhyN5YANQmm25OCgTEmKxH2CYaAIJbO3uYh8eYqmvJjgLXtw9m2wYuy8ByObgAbjUiMRfvdHkDnq83I1iEwAJ6w/6A4Gg45sFgkNEAfQuCmWq0wmL%2BBEwLGSBhpSIIaOSjFYL3qxDCwAAKiyXkcACL7M7oEAgM5coyYyVeBz7ACyaI8giY02IhwA7FZ7vs9fsvOkjPsxLRUKJoUTmazXsLOdy%2BazxabzUxLdbKZsdQ9dfqlSqGuqIC6LSQrfyTbQzaGNUKtVZNYL5n99an9gB6dOR6NusMe20ighikDJFjxEueNEE4jJBB4ZBEkO5mHHZAIRqYtP6kCF4hEkza7Ou6Fa4WZ/bvVkOBRDmP7VBUfb50Xi0vl1K0KskWv1xtR4ckMFtjubG6%2BrukfbHhjhWgKInx2fN0cZrOTqEzpsjhdLiMriubtWO4Nl%2Bh7HGEBCdvqA7el2eoptBiZ/Aher2kYjovJK/Zesh54GkawD7DyBYQUcsH6v%2BkIOGBbg8peHrMGwhbFqBfbnGqBAKGCrHhqy1zijSdIMi8FzRGE6B7tGYI8r8p4oWm163veZHIUhOFwhpdwQfsLBqgwEDzPG8n/ii6Jgv%2B0RojSl5cBoGjXPs0ReFQKl4f%2Ba7igSDCoEQDC7k5VBUHEJKYGSKxrDp0QwoOAUAHToG6TAGZecXpAAXpgBmjq5dypu5ZarpWQF1iB%2B4xuZRbipZNIOckTAweYCRlNFgo5am8n%2BrIelxBVxYeRK5zcg5yAQHVyZeq%2B%2Bx1QoSjoE%2BI75ngM75euRXbiVkkHi2bgWVZnpng8iYcIstCcAArLwfgcFopCoJwbjWNYIrkhFWw8KQBCaMdiwANYgGdZixZIkj%2BJsmr%2BCDGgA/4GiavonCSJdX23ZwvAKCAGgfV9ixwLAMCICgAj8MQulApg5CUGgdJ0HE6OwFTyQ08QACSYrgsgyTJES4JcP4RLCWcRKqAk0ioF8mToxw6YrqYljWGYGgZgAWkwGYAOqmhmADyZjHaQEAM0zrMoAYRiVHZt3iwIksALSikKstWJYCv7DbGtRq7avvOxrusglgj1nrBuoNT9As2KwBcGYXCW98DC2/bmyCo78uK27mtu97qK%2B5g/uOMg31BPg0J4GKMem8Axsp5Y%2Bh4NEdMGSd51I9dvB3RwKrE6TEUAGp4JgADucT7BAuCECQhwAlwhmbOmXAXVjrfzL9ICSAksWamdCRQ1wmoJGYZ1nZqAAc8McIjpAsCAB%2BkFdN3t2jGOL1oOP4xASCG2HFPB6Hgy7IYkdt6YywOCesmA%2B6Dy1qyK670aC0BpMQdGEBojIzEswYgaJODvTQY0NEWtojaChFg3gVM2CCC1gwTcyMsBOWAMiKMkt3pYFJsAcQrdSD4AuLUSEksbrvBqF4GkyMIKYFOuw2gddUQYI8FgZGg0r7cD1lQAwwAFAQIHlAxgxCZCCBEGIdgUgdHyCUGoZGuhy4AJQI9GuEj67wEWGLOOCciwO2sRYF26cPaZ1UD7G2ftDD509h6G2EiWCEAUG3SExAuRYAbosDoccXAMHcJ4VoegQjTFKOUPQqR0hxzGH4GOuTCgMD6FkuYthRFQjqJMApegEk1J6GUgYFRhg9DqTHM4TTMktIkPEl6Bim4cAXnfNunB9iqGPgkG2IsrwV32JUWKGglkjzHiON68xeCfSXvrJAywCDJEEd/T%2BcQIjsk4JM6Zsz/7GkWcsvhxcSClz0PwXRohxCGNecYlQ6h2HmNIAPVEyRiFDJGcjduWtBGHIIPORclyZmSDmQAhZ697kjw8L/WMU9NnP0LggS4WB4jJTERfK%2BAJYow02ArWylRJCajMAkeet9wWo1sHobZL99Zvw/iHRmX8KA/z5YMdmnNua835m6UKBAhYiw4ZgUBax1GaJgbwOBCCkEoPYTgjB2jtV4IIUQxRpBSGMAIBQqh7CaFeDoaaRhvBmEALYTdTh1SeHI34cgQR6x3oiLETdWxUjlQYHWDdeRIK%2BAqLUf3DR0DtFfL0R86QXzFA/LMdffQljq42FsXE2OEtODS0qlml26YVbq01umHWkS4gxNCvYyp9hEkQFcB0oIyTmmzFacU/JqTchFIKHHDt2TOlVM6Awbooxe2FIbdUrokwh0VK6ZOnI06l1TBKL06eSxwqDLPmC9h7cJmzJYAodm%2Bweb%2BFigLGFo9HlYs2NPLZ2NdkgH2dC45vKmZnLYBc49p7kDnt5leyVZxeC53HjEl5sgE0GKTbIFNpi/npsBUwYFijQUt3vpwSFBzBGwqPYik9Z6L3AZpGcdFn6w6TypTijlhcSW8DJVwWK89j4aAhsfXevMt6w2ZQe1l6MY50dfvAd%2BhNMUfsxSASO0c5UKvAdG5Vca6DqsoJqm6erdVhFwfgwhDhtEmvIZQzBlrMC0PoXebRDqjBOvtXgLhjg3XsI9V67RvrkYBtwTIkNWyuQKJ4IsZRTBVFKtjUa%2BN7zYNGIQ78m6uhNgZqMFYuWNi665scfmjgdsXFJ2LWnd2tBPZZ1Vn43OATA63SibW3NDTnDNuSa2jJG7O05IHZkVt3bMgLtabV8dtSp31NHXHCd66ZjDracutJnT509Ja1usKFI%2Bl7sw2MjgEypkIv2MAZAAGo4sdWXe6jj7cU4z2VCo5AqTnEG/eseFsztu7c2CxsDd7nkxwi/oiQcHBAxbTQllDaGAvLb41hjgOHoX4bu4ih7CzAZcAo5i6jmxaPYyGaS6%2Bl7QbH01BoSQlQEibAfSfM6IPVuPyE6j0gf06WxUPhofeUN2N0vYwlsRmwVsow4E%2BpeQzdaXwkBbUZnPucv0WFE9IzhJBAA%3D%3D%3D)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <memory_resource>

template <typename StringType = std::string>
struct MyContainer {
    using allocator_type = StringType::allocator_type;

    MyContainer(allocator_type allocator = {})
        // allocator_type = std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<char>
        : str_{ allocator } // expects allocator of type std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<char>
        , channels_ { allocator } // expects allocator of type std::polymorphic_allocator<int>
    {
        
    }

    StringType str_;

    using T = int;
    std::vector<T, typename std::allocator_traits<allocator_type>::template rebind_alloc<T>>
        channels_;
};


int main() {
    std::array<std::byte, 100> buf;
    std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource mbr{ buf.data(), buf.size() };
    std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<std::byte> pa{&mbr};
    
    MyContainer<std::pmr::string> c(pa); // passed allocator type is std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<std::byte>
}
```

As you can see, the allocator type passed to the MyContainer instance is just `std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<std::byte>`, even though it would expect an `std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<char>` which is derived from the string type. Then again, the vector object inside the MyContainer class would actually need an `std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<int>`, however it gobbles up the passed allocator (`std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<char>`) without problems. How does this work? Do allocators allow conversion into any other type of allocator per the standard? If so, why do I even need a `rebind_alloc`?

Comment: You need `rebind_alloc` to get the name of the type. Not to get [a converted value](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/polymorphic_allocator/polymorphic_allocator).

Comment: @BoP Ok got it but does the allocator specification require this conversion to be available? I see std::allocator defining a converting constructor as well.

Comment: Yes, the conversion is required. Many standard containers need to rebind their allocator. For example, a `std::list<T>` doesn't allocate T's, but some internal struct holding a T and a pair of pointers (to get the links in the linked list).